# How can I have a bottom page border higher up on the last page in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to recreate the effect seen in the image below, where the bottom page border always appears the same distance from the text, so that on the last page it appears higher up on the page.

[image]

Comment: @MátéJuhász How would I do that manual adjustment?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to move the footer.  For the  border: use a table of one cell instead of page border.

Comment: Try inserting a section break before the page, then make the bottom margin much bigger as needed on the last page.